# Integrands with both dummy and actual variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

There's this integral;
$$y= \int_1^xx\sqrt{\ln t}dt$$

And I'm supposed to calculate $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ at $x=e$.

What does this even mean? I saw a solution to it where x was just taken out and the integral done afterward as usual, which doesn't really make sense to me.

If it's not some typo, what exactly does it mean when a free variable's in the integrand?

Comment: $x$ is a  constanat as far as integration w.r.t $t$ is concerned.

Comment: Use Leibnitz rule.

Comment: When you calculating the second degree differential, though, doesn't that change?

Comment: @Koro: I was trying to, but I don't know how the function will look in this case. Moreover, I don't understand, intuitively, what the function means.

Comment: @HarryHolmes: $y= x\times \int_1^{x} \sqrt {\ln t} dt$. Now can you take it from here?

Comment: @Koro: yes, but how *that* came about is what I don't understand.

Comment: @HarryHolmes: $t$ is a dummy variable here. So you can take out $x$ from the integrand as with respect to $t$, it is constant.

Comment: Oh, because no matter what the value of x is, the value of the integral itself will only be multiplied by it and not changed in any other way, right?

Comment: @HarryHolmes: In this case, yes!

Comment: Right, got it, thanks